# Pass a control instance reference from a view to a model view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding

Attempts to pass a control instance reference from a view to a model view.

- First, it's very slow, I use `ToasMessage` property before it is set by the view.
- Secondly, the control `Toast` first sends null and then instance references.

What am I doing wrong or what else am I missing to make it work properly?

in Control

```
public class Toast : Control, IToastMessage
{
  public Toast()
  {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
      ToastInstance = this;
    });
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ToastInstanceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ToastInstance", typeof(IToastMessage), typeof(Toast), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

  public IToastMessage ToastInstance
  {
    get { return (IToastMessage)GetValue(ToastInstanceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ToastInstanceProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

in ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public IToastMessage ToastMessage {private get; set;}
}
```

in View:

```xml
<custom:Toast
  ToastInstance="{Binding ToastMessage, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Comment: If your intent is to pass to the view model the instance of a control, just create a constructor of the view model which takes the reference and call it in the constructor of the view while creating it. It's not theoretically correct to have a reference to a control in the view model but sometime it's necessary also for a better comprehension of the code

Comment: It was enough just that I moved the first use to the event: `public event EventHandler ContentRendered`. :)